# how to responsive design with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

going to responsive design with bootstrap following menu segment. how to make me responsive design

```
<a href="#menu" id="toggle" name="toggle"></a>

<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: study guide tutorials links is OK.

Comment: Bootstrap provides a very good documentation for bootstrap 3 http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar and bootstrap 4 https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/ . There you should find all you need

Answer (score 0):

you can use bootstrap drop down like this :

```
 <li role="presentation" class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop4" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Dropdown <span class="caret"></span> </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1" aria-labelledby="drop4">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: OK I need full screen menu bar when browse mobile or tab